# Is there a name of a style of these pictures?

Tags: style-identification

[image]

[image]

I know that there is something connecting the style of these two pictures. But i don't know what. I like that kind of style with geometrical shapes and things. But i've been googling for bauhaus, mid-century modern, swiss style and it seems like it takes a mix of them all but no name for this exact style.

Comment: I see some similarities between your two examples, but I'm not sure there is a name for this. Do you want a name so you can find more examples? It would be pretty easy to draw something like this yourself. Basic geometric shapes (circles, triangles, squares, stars), simple wire frames. White strokes dividing colored shapes, colored strokes around white shapes. Vivid, clean but slightly faded colors.

Comment: There seems to be some psychedelic elements mixed in there along with International design style (eyes out of nowhere, rays, the sort of loopy shape in the top image in the top right corner, flashy colors on the top image especially). Maybe not a coincidence since they were both current styles in the 60s